# Types and names should match

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, strong-typing

For the given named object of type `t`,

```
interface t {
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: string
}

let obj:t = {
    a: "foo",
    b: 12,
    c: "bar"
}
```

below is the function processing this named object,

```
function keepWholeObject(obj_param: {x: string, y:number}){
    let {a, b}:{a: string, b: number} = obj_param;
    console.log(`In function - ${a}`);
    console.log(`In function - ${b}`);
}
```

where

`let {a, b}:{a: string, b: number} = obj_param;` does not work.

Because, types as well as names should match. Error is: `Type '{ x: string; y: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; b: number; }'. Property 'a' is missing in type '{ x: string; y: number; }'`

---

> A **pitfall** of **structural typing** versus nominative typing is that two separately defined types intended for different purposes, but accidentally holding the same properties (e.g. both composed of a pair of integers), could be considered the same type by the type system, simply because they happen to have identical structure. One way this can be avoided is by **creating one algebraic data type(composite type)** for each use. [taken from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system)

This is why in my above function declaration, I have declared parameters using composite type de-structured as `obj_param: {a: string, b:number}` but not `{a, b}: {a: string, b:number}` to avoid duplicate identifiers. **Side effects** of matching both names and types.

---

Why TypeScript does not allow assignment of object having identical types?  structural typing?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of type-safety? If the properties (names) are different, the object is different. So cannot be assigned, right?

Comment: @binDebug Matching types(memory structure) wouldn't suffice for type safety?

Comment: Type safety is, as the name suggests, matching design types. Theoretically a person can have number (age) and string (name) and a car can have number (price) and string (name). One can't be assigned to the other, right?

Comment: @binDebug Structural type system defined in wiki: *an element is considered to be compatible with another if, for each feature within the second element's type, a corresponding and identical feature exists in the first element's type. **Some languages may differ** on the details, such as whether the features **must match in name**. This definition is **not symmetric**, and includes subtype compatibility. Two types are considered to be identical if each is compatible with the other*. I think, GO is on same lines with TypeScript, in terms of type equivalence.

Comment: @overexchange But `{a, b}` and `{x, y}` *don't* have a matching memory structure? That's exactly what the compiler error is telling you. Objects aren't tuples, they are records.

Comment: I don't see what the `interface t` declaration and your quote about nominative typing have to do with the question.

Comment: @Bergi 1) Explicit typing is recommended, so `obj:t`. 2) Quote is about the reason, why I could not write `{a, b}: {a: string, b:number}` as function parameter? let me edit... Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Bergi `{a, b}` & `{x, y}` have matching memory structure because `a` is same type(`string`) as `x` & `b` is same type(`number`) as `y`. It is the data type that decides the memory structure

Comment: @overexchange No, they do not have the same structure. They have different properties. Again, we are not dealing with tuples here.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, we are not dealing with tuples here, but they have same properties(`string` & `number`). Datatype of each property decides the memory structure.

Comment: I think you’re misunderstanding. The property value types are the same, but the properties themselves are not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, properties are not same  because names are different. My point is memory structure is decided by type of the property but not name

Comment: The error seems to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2**

```
type Point = { x: number, y: string};
type Vector2 = { 0: number, 1: string}
let p :Point;
let v :Vector2 = p;
```

Similarly here there are also two options.

1. Throw error as types are incompatible.
2. Convert values to appropriate fields, so we don't have to some extra stuff.

Option 1 has the highest priority. As mentioned by @binDebug this is why this language was built.

**Edit**

When typescript will converted to js, it will look like

```
function keepWholeObject(obj_param){
    let {a, b} = obj_param;
    console.log(`In function - ${a}`);
    console.log(`In function - ${b}`);
}
```

Without any type information.

**Previous Answer**

```
function keepWholeObject(obj_param: { a: string, b: number }) {
  let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = obj_param;
  console.log(`In function - ${a}`);
  console.log(`In function - ${b}`);
}
```

1. `obj_param: { a: string, b: number }` will work not with `x` and `y`.
2. Types are compile time feature and are erased at run time.
3. Destructuring is a javascript feature. To sum up javascript destructuring works like that.

Comment: Please read the question again.. What the code looks like in JS is an abstraction for me.. after using TypeScript